# Oracle 11g - Running PL/SQL Cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle11g

I'm trying to run this code on Oracle 11g and it's giving me the error below. I can't seem to get it right.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR bookcursor IS
    SELECT btName, BookCopy.Isbn, pubName, dateDestroyed
      FROM booktitle bt
      JOIN publisher p
        ON bt.pubId = p.pubId 
      JOIN bookcopy bc
        ON bt.Isbn = bc.Isbn 
     WHERE datedestroyed IS NULL
    ;
    bookcursorrec bookcursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN bookcursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH bookcursor INTO bookcursorrer;
        EXIT WHEN bookcursor%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line( 'ISBN: ' ||bookcursorrec.isbn
                              || ' - Book Name: ' || bookcursorrec.btname
                              || ' - Publisher: ' || bookcursorrec.pubname );
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE bookcursor;
END;


ERROR at line 3:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 20:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "BOOKCOPY"."ISBN": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'BOOKCURSOR' is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 11, column 19:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 15, column 31:
PLS-00201: identifier 'BOOKCURSORRER' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 15, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 17, column 42:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 17, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can you kindly point me to what is wrong? I can't seem to understand to what is wrong

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- You need a semicolon after the cursor definition (i.e., after the query).
- You can't use `bookCursor` both as the name of the cursor and as the name of the record you fetch. (I notice that a bit of your code uses `bookCursorRec` for the latter, so I'll go with that.)
- The `fetch` needs to fetch *into* something, that is, into `bookCursorRec`.
- You need a semicolon after the call to `dbms_output.put_line`.
- Your query seems wrong; it looks like both joins are cross-joins.

Putting it together, and adjusting the formatting and structure a bit so it's slightly more "idiomatic" PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR bookcursor IS
    SELECT btname, isbn, pubname, datedestroyed
      FROM booktitle bt
      JOIN publisher p
        ON bt.pid = p.id -- this is just a guess
      JOIN bookcopy bc
        ON bt.bcid = bc.id -- this is just a guess
     WHERE datedestroyed IS NULL
    ;
    bookcursorrec bookcursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN bookcursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH bookcursor INTO bookcursorrec;
        EXIT WHEN bookcursor%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line( 'ISBN: ' ||bookcursorrec.isbn
                              || ' - Book Name: ' || bookcursorrec.btname
                              || ' - Publisher: ' || bookcursorrec.pubname );
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE bookcursor;
END;
/
```

By the way, Oracle identifiers are mostly case-sensitive (in that they're implicitly converted to uppercase unless you wrap them in double-quotes), so usually people will use identifiers like `book_cursor_rec` and `date_destroyed` rather than `bookCursorRec` (= `bookcursorrec`) and `dateDestroyed` (= `datedestroyed`).

Comment: ruakh I get this error: ERROR at line 14:
ORA-06550: line 14, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "FETCH" to continue.

Comment: @Brian: Oh, oops, you're also missing a semicolon after your `dbms_output.put_line(...)` statement. I'll update my answer with that, and some other problems I see . . .

Comment: Hi, I update the code in my main answer with a new error. I can't seem to get this right:/

Comment: @Brian: The first error ("column ambiguously defined") is because you have an `isbn` in both `booktitle` and `bookcopy`, so Oracle can't tell which one you mean. (Technically they're equivalent, due to the join, but Oracle doesn't recognize that.) So you need to change the `isbn` in your `SELECT` clause to either `booktitle.isbn` or `bookcopy.isbn` (as you prefer). I believe the second error ("declaration of cursor 'BOOKCURSOR' is incomplete or malformed") is a result of the first error: once you fix the query, that should go away.

Comment: @Brian: The third error ("identifier 'BOOKCURSORRE' must be declared") is because I briefly had a typo in my answer (writing `bookcursorre` instead of `bookcursorrrec`), and you copied-and-pasted at just the wrong time. Sorry about that!

Comment: I fixed what you told me and I still more error messages. Is Oracle that buggy?

Comment: @Brian: The first error -- try `bc.isbn` (using the alias) instead of `bookcopy.isbn`. The second error -- caused by the first. The third error -- you typo'd. The fourth error -- caused by the second.

Comment: @Brian: It's not that Oracle is buggy, it's that the debugging loop becomes slower and more noticeable when you have to post every error on StackOverflow and wait for feedback. Most of these error-messages are caused by small errors that are quickly fixed in normal circumstances, when the person typing into SQL*Plus is doing the debugging.

Comment: (Don't get me wrong -- Oracle *is* buggy; for example, a query that runs very weekly, many times an hour, for weeks, can suddenly crash and become incredibly slow for no apparent reason. But Oracle bugginess isn't the problem in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
 fetch  bookCursor
```

into

```
 fetch bookCursor into bookCursorRec;
```

above the `while`.

Also

```
cursor bookCursor is
       SELECT btName, ISBN, pubName, dateDestroyed
       FROM BookTitle bt, publisher p, BookCopy bc
       WHERE bt.bcId = bcId
       AND dateDestroyed is null
       bookCursor bookCursor%rowtype;
```

should read

```
cursor bookCursor is
       SELECT btName, ISBN, pubName, dateDestroyed
       FROM BookTitle bt, publisher p, BookCopy bc
       WHERE bt.bcId = bcId
       AND dateDestroyed is null;

       bookCursorRec bookCursor%rowtype;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Serveroutput on
CREATE OR REPLACE A PROCEDURE TO GET_SENRYO_EMP
DECLARE
    CURSOR Senryocursor IS
    SELECT first_name, last_name, full_Name,Gender,DOB,Martialstatus,Nationality,Telephone,Email_id,job,Nationalidentifier,Hire_date
      FROM Senryo;
--Senryocursorrec senryocursor%rowtype;
BEGIN
 OPEN Senryocursor;
LOOP
        FETCH Senryocursor INTO Senryocursorrec;
        EXIT WHEN Senryocursor%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line( 'Senryocursor ' ||Senryocursorrec
                              || '- Full_name :' || Senryocursorrec.full_name
                              || ' - Job: ' || Senryocursorrec.Job );
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE Senryocursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also important to check user has select grant to the object or table in question.
My issue got resolved by granting user select access to table used in cursor;

```
GRANT SELECT ON <table> TO <user> ;
```