# PLS-00201: identifier 'CURSOR' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I saw that have many similar questions here in stackoverflow but no one answer my question.

Where is the problem ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "PR_TESTE"( sl_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)  
IS
    stm varchar(30000);
BEGIN
    stm := 'SELECT * from tb_device_type';
    OPEN sl_cursor FOR  stm ;
END;
```

Comment: Don't you need a `DECLARE CURSOR` statement?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that procedure definition.  When fdo you get that error?

Comment: I get this message when i try execute the procedure. I though maybe could be some special permission, but i realy don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem in your code. The problem could be in the function/proc calling this procedure. Make sure that the cursor is defined there.
I replaced your table tb_device_type to tab. This snippet works fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "PR_TESTE"( sl_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)  
IS
    stm varchar(30000);
BEGIN
    stm := 'SELECT * from tab';
    OPEN sl_cursor FOR  stm ;
END;

-----
declare
  l_cur  sys_refcursor;
  l_tname tab.tname%type;
  l_tabtype tab.tabtype%type;
  l_clusterid tab.clusterid%type;
begin
  pr_teste(l_cur);
  loop
    fetch l_cur into l_tname, l_tabtype, l_clusterid;
    exit when l_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_tname);
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

[Oracle 11g - Running PL/SQL Cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811114/oracle-11g-running-pl-sql-cursors)

and

[Oracle Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)